# The implementation of functional “Recolor”

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, photoshop

Have a task:
All points of the pictures affixed the user-Hue (0-360), Saturation (0-100)
We take the initial point transform Lightness (-100-0-100) and transformed as follows:

[image: http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=9d0ad31f45b9c32460ec0a6142df435a]

I do not understand what it is about? What is shown in the graph? how to change the Lightness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle line is the pixel value going from for example 0 to 255.

The upper line shows adding 50% lightness. For a input value of 0 (the middle line) it will actually be 50% added, but as you get closer to max value (255) the value is scaled to avoid value becoming > 255.

The bottom line do the same but the opposite way, subtracting 50%. At an input value of 0 there is no change. Only at max value you will actually be able to reduce lightness by 50%.

The model you're referring to is a HSL (or HSV) model. To adjust hue, saturation and luma you can convert RGB model into HSL first, then adjust the L for brightness, and then convert back.

I have a fiddler with a palette which uses this here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/wYBEU/

There are two functions in there, `rgb2hsv()` and `hsv2rgb` which shows the math:

The process would be `rgb2hsv -> adjust L -> hsv2rgb` (unless you can use HSL directly).

RGB to HSV:

```
function rgb2hsv() {

    var rr, gg, bb,

    r = arguments[0] / 255,
    g = arguments[1] / 255,
    b = arguments[2] / 255,
    h, s,

    v = Math.max(r, g, b),
    diff = v - Math.min(r, g, b),
    diffc = function (c) {
        return (v - c) / 6 / diff + 0.5;
    };

    if (diff === 0) {
        h = s = 0;

    } else {
        s = diff / v;

        rr = diffc(r);
        gg = diffc(g);
        bb = diffc(b);

        if (r === v) {h = bb - gg}
        else if (g === v) {h = (0.3333333333) + rr - bb} 
        else if (b === v) {h = (0.6666666667) + gg - rr};
        if (h < 0) {h += 1}
        else if (h > 1) {h -= 1}
    }

    return {
        h: h * 360,
        s: s * 100,
        v: v * 100
    }
};
```

HSV to RGB:

```
function hsv2rgb(h, s, v) {

    h /= 60;
    s *= 0.01;
    v *= 0.01;

    var i = Math.floor(h);
    var f = h - i;
    var m = v * (1 - s);
    var n = v * (1 - s * f);
    var k = v * (1 - s * (1 - f));
    var rgb;

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            rgb = [v, k, m];
            break;
        case 1:
            rgb = [n, v, m];
            break;
        case 2:
            rgb = [m, v, k];
            break;
        case 3:
            rgb = [m, n, v];
            break;
        case 4:
            rgb = [k, m, v];
            break;
        case 5:
        case 6:
            rgb = [v, m, n];
        break;
    }

    return {
        r: rgb[0] * 255 |0,
        g: rgb[1] * 255 |0,
        b: rgb[2] * 255 |0
    }
}
```

Example:

Lets say you have this RGB value -

[image: RGB - HSV]

Thatv would give you HSV 219, 95 and 100 for luma.

All you need to do now is to adjust luma to, say 50 and feed it through hsv2rgb

```
var rgb = hsv2rgb(219, 95, 50);
```

`rgb` (`rgb.r`, `rgb.g`, `rgb.b`) now contains the new rgb values with adjusted luma.

Comment: Thnx. Can I more learn something? You explained everything clearly. But you can detail about the change Lightness? How can I change along two lines at once?) Sorry if the question is stupid)))I have not previously worked with graphics :(

Comment: @GeraySuinov Sure, I added a formula to the answer (from the top of my head). The color values must be between 0 and 255 as usual. Brightness is a value between -1 and 1, 0 = no adjustment. Hope this helps.

Comment: @GeraySuinov Somehow I missed (even if I read it clearly) you're using HSL - added process for this instead.

Comment: So i Must convert to HSL -> do something with L -> convert toRGB ?)

Comment: @GeraySuinov Correct, unless data already is in HSL color space.

Comment: Sorry if I bored. Would you like to write just need to change the L. For me to write a function works not correctly. I have pixels RGB. User set Hue,Saturation,Lightness.

Comment: @GeraySuinov If you go to my link (as in the answer) http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/wYBEU/ you can study how the conversion can be done. (In Chrome you will see two sliders at the bottom which adjust S and the last L - see the code for that one).

Comment: @GeraySuinov added example in answer (that deserves an up-vote) ;)